# Circular Integrator Operator in SystemVerilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am currently working on a project about mixed-signal IC design using SystemVerilog - Real Number Modeling (RNM). 
I have to convert an expression argument into its integrated form.
I know there is a circular integrator operator in Verilog-A, `idtmod()`, but until now, I have not managed to find any equal operator in SystemVerilog.

If anyone has any knowledge about this matter, I would much appreciate it.

Comment: As far as I know this doesn't exist so you might need to write your own function. If you give more details about what you are trying to accomplish we can be more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in SystemVerilog. Verilog-A works in the continuous time domain and knows how to compute integral expressions over a time period. SystemVerilog works with discrete time events. It can only sample a signal at a particular time. So depending on the expression you want integrated, you need to approximate the integral over the sample period.